# Passing an unspecified numpy array as an argument to a function

Tags: python, arrays

I want to be able to define a function as having an argument of an unspecified array. For example,

```
import numpy as np
def cols(np.array([]): 
    return len(np.array([])
```

Say that:

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Then I want `cols(x)` to give output 3.

Note, the input must be a np.array, so please no workaround to that!

Comment: `def cols(arr)`? and why would you think this array gives you length of 3?

Comment: @Guy yupp this solved it

Comment: In you example, `len(x)` is equal to 2. If you want to get the size of the nested arrays (in other words the number of columns of `x`), you can use `x.shape[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify what is your argument in python

```py
import numpy as np

def cols(arr):
    return arr.shape[1]

number_of_cols = cols(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
print(number_of_cols) # will print 3
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite new and this fixed it